# IONIC . Select item inside array

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I wanted to create 2 list of  `ion-item`, like this:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Gaming</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="gaming">
      <ion-option value="nes">NES</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="n64">Nintendo64</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="ps">PlayStation</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

but my question is, is it possible that I want the `ion-option` to be in a list of arrays so that the 2nd list of item will only show `ion-option` that are not selected from the 1st one.

e.g.: 1st list **NES** where selected so the 2nd list will only show **Nintendo64** and **PlayStation**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a dirty way but it works.

1. Declare array and object variables in `.ts` file.

**code:**

```
gamingList1 = [{ "value":"nes", "label":"NES" },{ "value":"n64", "label":"Nintendo64" },{ "value":"ps", "label":"PlayStation" }];
gamingList2:any = [];
gaming = { firstGaming:"", secondGaming:"" }
```

2. Create a function to populate the second array.

**code:**

```
populateSelect(value) {
  this.gamingList2 = [];
  for (let gl of this.gamingList1) {
    if(value !== gl.value) {
      this.gamingList2.push({"value":gl.value, "label":gl.label});
    }
  }
  this.gaming.secondGaming = this.gamingList2[0].value;
}
```

3. Load it inside constructor for initial `ion-select` data.

**code:**

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
  this.gaming.firstGaming = this.gamingList1[0].value;
  this.populateSelect(this.gaming.firstGaming);
}
```

4. Display it in HTML.

```html
<ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Gaming</ion-label>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="gaming.firstGaming" (ngModelChange)="populateSelect(gaming.firstGaming)">
        <ion-option [value]="gl.value" *ngFor="let gl of gamingList1">{{gl.label}}</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Gaming</ion-label>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="gaming.secondGaming">
        <ion-option [value]="gl.value" *ngFor="let gl of gamingList2">{{gl.label}}</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```